# Generating and distributing unique usernames with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was trying to generate unique usernames from server side and distribute those to the users by using their personal details, which they enter while registering into the login form. This is to make more secured usernames and to avoid hacking.

So, here is my question: How to generate unique and unpredictable usernames out of their personal information like first name, last name, age and date of birth. The usernames should not follow any sequence like we have now in our registration forms like gmail. Nothing like using the first initial and last name or 3letters from first name and so on.. 
The usernames should be purely unpredictable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For what it's worth, this is security through obscurity and is unlikely to provide any real security benefit. You should let users pick a username that they can remember and store their passwords using a salted hash, lock accounts after several failed attempts, etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Answer (score 1):

Why would you make the names depend on their details then? Just generate some uniformly distributed strings of letters like `vwneuibx` (long enough, so that you don't run out of names soon), no one would guess such a name, but it wouldn't be easy to remember it too.

More secure way is taking a hash of some salt and the personal data you specified.

Answer (score 0):

idk maybe something like this...

```
function random_name($length){
    $characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $name = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $name .= $characters[mt_rand(0,strlen($characters) - 1)];

        }
        return $_POST['first'].$name;

    }
```

Comment: If you use `$characters = $firstName.$lastName.$age.$dateOfBirth;` then you will even fulfill the requirement of using the personal information to generate the names!

Comment: @matt didn't even consider that but that is true! Good Stuff!

Comment: @matt and Easley thanks for your great help! I will post my work once I finish it. Right now I am working on it in a different approach but I will let you know. Any suggestions and comments are appreciable.